# How do you modify a dictionary from a text file when you only need to get specific values?

Tags: python, file, dictionary

So say we have some sort of file with maybe like 6 columns, and 6 rows. If I wanted to get one specific column that reads one line, and modify a current dictionary I have, how would I approach that?

The output should be all the data with the the key being the second column, and the 2 values being the first column and 4th column?

Can somebody please help me start this off?

I've tried using:

```
for line in file:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        data[int(key)] = val
    print (data)
```

But, obviously this'll fail, since this expects only 2 values. I need 1 key value, and 2 value values.

Answer (score 0):

`split` returns a `list`. Use the list instead of expanding into named variables.

```
data = {}
for line in file:
    row = line.strip().split()
    data[int(row[1])] = row[0], row[3]
print (data)
```